# Can't connect monitor with vga cable ubuntu 18.04.3

Tags: dell, intel, monitor, vga

My Laptop ([Dell Latitude e5270](https://www.dell.com/support/search/us/en/04#q=Latitude%20e5270&sort=relevancy&f:iuxType=[Manuals%20%26%20Documentation]&f:langFacet=[en])) can't be connected with monitor via vga cable (hdmi works good). If I plug it in, nothing happens; I can only use the built-in screen (or any HDMI monitor I plug it into).

That VGA monitor itself works, as I use it with other devices and it connects fine through the cable. My laptop connected without any problems to a VGA monitor on Ubuntu 17 version i think.

Intel® HD Graphics 520

xrandr while the VGA is plugged in:

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1366 x 768, maximum 8192 x 8192
XWAYLAND0 connected 1366x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y 
axis) 280mm x 160mm
1366x768      59.98*+
```

xrand --verbose

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1366 x 768, maximum 8192 x 8192
XWAYLAND0 connected 1366x768+0+0 (0x24) normal (normal left inverted 
right x axis y axis) 280mm x 160mm
Identifier: 0x21
Timestamp:  28178
Subpixel:   unknown
Gamma:      1.0:1.0:1.0
Brightness: 0.0
Clones:    
CRTC:       0
CRTCs:      0
Transform:  1.000000 0.000000 0.000000
            0.000000 1.000000 0.000000
            0.000000 0.000000 1.000000
           filter: 
  1366x768 (0x24) 85.000MHz -HSync +VSync *current +preferred
  h: width  1366 start 1431 end 1567 total 1776 skew    0 clock  
  47.86KHz
  v: height  768 start  771 end  781 total  798           clock  
  59.98Hz
```

lspci

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th 
Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 08)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Skylake GT2 [HD 
Graphics 520] (rev 07)
00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 
v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor Thermal Subsystem (rev 08)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP USB 3.0 
xHCI Controller (rev 21)
00:14.2 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point- 
LP Thermal subsystem (rev 21)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP 
CSME HECI #1 (rev 21)
00:16.3 Serial controller: Intel Corporation Device 9d3d (rev 21)
00:17.0 RAID bus controller: Intel Corporation 82801 Mobile SATA 
Controller [RAID mode] (rev 21)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express 
Root Port #5 (rev f1)
00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 9d1a (rev f1)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP LPC Controller 
(rev 21) 
00:1f.2 Memory controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PMC (rev 
21)
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio (rev 
21)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP SMBus (rev 21)
00:1f.6 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection 
I219-LM (rev 21)
01:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 8260 (rev 3a)
02:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. 
RTS525A PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
```

lspci -k | grep -A 2 -i "VGA"

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Skylake GT2 [HD 
Graphics 520] (rev 07)
Subsystem: Dell Skylake GT2 [HD Graphics 520]
Kernel driver in use: i915
```

Comment: No, that is a build in monitor of laptop

Comment: Resolution is 1920x1080 60hz.

Comment: HP 22f - https://support.hp.com/my-en/document/c05873308
But i also have and HP 22W and i'ts same problem

Comment: I tried this cable on another Laptop and it's work. Monitors too.

Comment: Another cable - nothing. Monitor menu show that the VGA is inactive.

Comment: long shot but some usb hubs have a  vga output on them.

Comment: I bought a Dell dock station now but it's same problem. DVI and VGA outputs is like VGA output on laptop